# What is a sublinear function? Is $y'(x) = x^5(e^{4-y^2}-1)$ sublinear?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, recreational-mathematics

May I have any simplest definition of sublinear function? I tried reading through Wikipedia but couldn't understand it well. Moreover, how can I check whether any function follows sublinearity or not? Also, does sublinearity implies global Lipschitzness?

Comment: Let $V$ be a $K-$vector spaces. The function $f:V\to K$ is sublinear if for all $x,y\in V$ and all $\lambda \in K$, $$f(x+\lambda y)\leq f(x)+\lambda f(y).$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is even bounded in $y$. So you get
$$
|y'|\le |x|^5(e^4-1)
$$
which implies
$$
|y(x)-y(0)|\le \frac{|x|^6}6(e^4-1).
$$
This is the kind of bound one can use to show that the maximal domain is $\Bbb R$.

In general an ODE is sub-linear if $|f(x,y)|\le K(x)+L(x)|y|$. In a slightly restricted but more simple version one can also find $|f(x,y)|\le L|y|$ for $|y|>R$ for some radius $R$ and constant $L$.

Comment: Thank you so much